# RDP session re-locks right after login

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, rdp

For some reason, after users do the initial authentication, the system logs in (or unlocks) and locks the screen again within a few seconds (without dropping the RDP session). I've seen this on XP SP3 and Server 2k3. Clients are both major versions of the MS client, and rdesktop.

Update:
We've seen the issue on a range of machines from 2k3 server (no logon/post logon scripts on servers) to XP SP3. Multiple machines have the same issue - even coming from a fresh and fully patched install.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before but back a long time ago in NT days. There was a problem with the login script being run upon accessing the server via RDP that was mis-interpereted by the server and auto locked it. A problem if you had no way to do ctrl-alt-del on a rdp session.

Things i would try in order to narrow the problem down:

- Does it affect all users?
- Does it happen on other servers?

(this should tell you if its user or machine specific).

After that I would look at group policy stuff.

What os is the machine you are connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about remote session but have seen exactly the same behavior on local system logon: that was caused by removed or damaged userinit.exe ...